# Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: _babel_runtime_helpers_toConsumableArray__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default is not defined

Tags: node.js, webpack, web-scraping, babeljs, puppeteer

I am getting this error, when I try to run the script (which uses webpack)

```
Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: _babel_runtime_helpers_toConsumableArray__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default is not defined     at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:27
```

but when I run same code which doesn't use webpack I got the expected result.

here is my function.

```
const getMeenaClickProducts = async (title) => {
  const url = ` ${MEENACLICK}/${title}`;

  console.log({ url });

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitForSelector('.ant-pagination-total-text');

  const products = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const cards = [...document.querySelectorAll('.card-thumb')];
    console.log({ cards });

    return cards.map((card) => {
      const productTitle = card.querySelector('.title').innerText;
      const priceElement = card.querySelector('.reg-price');
      const price = priceElement ? priceElement.innerText : '';
      const image = card.querySelector('.img').src;
      const link = card.querySelector('.main-link').href;

      return {
        title: productTitle,
        price,
        image,
        link,
      };
    });
  });

  await browser.close();

  const filteredProducts = products
    .filter((product) =>
      product.title.toLowerCase().includes(title.toLowerCase())
    )
    .filter((item) => item.price);

  return filteredProducts;
};
```

what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Babel, and with this part:

```
  const products = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const cards = [...document.querySelectorAll('.card-thumb')];
    console.log({ cards });

    return cards.map((card) => {
      const productTitle = card.querySelector('.title').innerText;
      const priceElement = card.querySelector('.reg-price');
      const price = priceElement ? priceElement.innerText : '';
      const image = card.querySelector('.img').src;
      const link = card.querySelector('.main-link').href;

      return {
        title: productTitle,
        price,
        image,
        link,
      };
    });
  });
```

The inside of the `page.evaluate()` script you are passing as a function parameter, is not the actual code that is being passed to the page instance, because first you are using babel to transform it.
The array spread operator you have in this part:

```
    const cards = [...document.querySelectorAll('.card-thumb')];
```

Is most likely being transformed in your `build` to a function named `_babel_runtime_helpers_toConsumableArray__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default`, which is then passed to the puppeteer `page` context, and ultimately executed in that page. But such function is not defined in that context, that's why you get a ReferenceError.

Some options to fix it:

1. Don't use the spread operator combined with the current babel config you are using, so the transformed build doesn't includ a polyfill/replacement of it. Think of a replacement with an equivalent effect, such as:

```
    const cards = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.card-thumb'));
```

Or more traditional `for` / `forEach()` loops and build up the array yourself will get job done.

2. Update your babel config / target language level to support the spread operator natively.